# por que mi vídeo de alta calidad se detiene constantemente usando html?

Tags: html, css, html5

muestro un video en mi pagina web que ocupa toda la pantalla . este video pesa 450 mb por que tiene muy buena resolucion , el problema es que se detiende constatemente . supongo que es por la calidad del video. mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de solucionar este problema. he visto varias paginas web con videos de buena calidad que no tienen estos problemas. espero su ayuda gracias

les dejo mi codigo

```
  <div class="videoContainer">
      <video autoplay muted loop >
        <source src="images/video_portada.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un video de 450MB en una página web?

Comment: Si, quisiera saber cual es la mejor solucion en estos casos . para que el video se pueda ver correctamente

Comment: ¿El vídeo está de fondo o es un vídeo normal con el que los usuarios interactúan? ¿Podrías añadir el código que tienes para añadir el vídeo a la página?

Comment: Lo mas recomendable en estos casos es publicar el video en sitios externos como youtube o vimeo y enlazarlo en tu pagina web para evitar el consumo excesivo de ancho de banda.